# While Editing SharePoint master page to hide site Titile, I am not able to find DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, edit

I am editing a SharePoint Online master page.

Commented out below mention, complete h1 section but still site title "Trial" is showing on the page.

[image]

---

```
<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
    runat="server"
    RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
    SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider"
SkipLinkText="">-->
<!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><span id="ctl00_DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">Home</span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
<!--SPM:<PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:</PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta BlockElement="true" id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription" CssClass="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap" runat="server">-->
<a href="javascript:;" id="ms-pageDescriptionDiv" style="display:none" data-accessibility-nocheck="true">
    <span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage">
    </span>
</a>
<span class="ms-accessible" id="ms-pageDescription">
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"/>-->
</span>
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout");-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Comment: I see there is function being called for setting up Page description. Can you remove third last line which is `<!--SPM:_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout");-->` and check if its working.

Comment: thanks @PradipR. for your input.  please see my answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried by removing the funtion suggested by @PradipR (in fist comment) but nothing happen Site title was still there.
So I tried by removing other functions as well (one at a time only but no luck.

Then I tried removing all the function at once under the **h1** tag. Still that site title was visible.

Finally, I remove the whole **h1** tag from the code and now the Site title is vanished.

Don't know if it is as per best practice or not but my concern is solved finally. ;)